# Ajax page refresh fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

I am trying to refresh the page with ajax whenever a button to submit a form (and change the data on the page), it however; is not working.
I have looked through several tutorials and the api, checked my syntax, but I cannot get it to work.
Could you please have a look at it?
The updating itself is called upon success in 2 methods, which DO succeed.
The updating itself the method update(ajax).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: NO browser errors or whatsoever. The page is simply not refreshing.

Comment: Are there any errors thrown by the browser?And, why don't you use jquery ajax methods rather than XMLHttpRequest in the update() function?

Comment: No browser errors or whatsoever. The page is simply not refreshing.
I have not looked into jquery just yet. I've seen this method during college, so I was assuming it would work just fine.

Comment: You know AJAX was made so you can submit a form WITHOUT refreshing the page. But if you really need to, just put a `location.reload()` inside of the success/done callback.

Comment: My purpose was to refresh the contents of the whole page, so basically refreshing the whole page, when submitting the form.

Comment: I see. Then you wanted to show the ajax response inside of your container after refreshing the page? It might be a little hard without cookies or server-side coding.

Comment: I am not sure what the html code is.. However, did you miss select chars in your code? $("submitdelete") might be $("#submitdelete") or $(".submitdelete").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared xmlhttp and checked status of request object (which doesn't exist).

```
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
        cont.innerHTML = request.responseText;}, false);
```

replace request with xmlhttp in the above lines of code.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but unfortunately, that does not fix the problem. I have edited my main post and provided the altered code.

Comment: Then set break points in your code and find out where the execution stops.